# Checkbox in Gridview not being checked on setSelection()

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-checkbox

I have a gridview whose item layout implements checkable, thus the gridview can handle checking a checkbox within the item layout when an item is selected. This all works fine except for setting a gridview item selected programatically. The check box doesn't look selected but something must be happening in the background as selecting the item after that leaves it unchecked and upon selecting again it becomes checked.

Any ideas?

Edit: It seems that the staying unselected on click was due to some other logic in my code so that could be a red herring to the actual issue.

Checkable layout

```
public class WeedFilterItem extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {

private TextView label;
private CheckBox checkBox;
private boolean mChecked;

public WeedFilterItem(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public WeedFilterItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public WeedFilterItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.weed_filter_item, this);
    this.label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filter_textview);
    this.checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    mChecked = checked;
    this.checkBox.setChecked(checked);
}

public boolean isChecked() {
    return mChecked;
}

public void toggle() {
    setChecked(!mChecked);
}
}
```

item layout xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleX="1.5"
        android:scaleY="1.5"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filter_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Setting up gridview

```
final GridView filters = (GridView) child.findViewById(R.id.filter_gridview);
final WeedFilterGridViewAdapter adapter = new WeedFilterGridViewAdapter(this, values);
filters.setAdapter(adapter);
filters.setSelection(0);
```

Everything else is handled by a stock gridview, just trying to call `gridView.setSelection(int)` on it.

I've also tried storing the int for the selected item in the adapter and setting the checkbox selected manually in getView along with calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` but that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
final GridView filters = (GridView) child.findViewById(R.id.filter_gridview);
final WeedFilterGridViewAdapter adapter = new WeedFilterGridViewAdapter(this, values);
filters.setAdapter(adapter);
filters.setSelection(0);
// add this line
filters.setItemChecked(0, true);
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked(int, boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked(int,%20boolean))

> public void setItemChecked (int position, boolean value)
>
> Added in API level 1 Sets the checked state of the specified position.
>   The is only valid if the choice mode has been set to
>   CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE or CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE.
>
> Parameters position   The item whose checked state is to be checked
>   value The new checked state for the item

Comment: this didn't work I'm afraid, the state may also not be being changed to checked as that was due to some other logic in my code.

Comment: tried notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter also, I added code snippets of the layout.

Comment: @DemandedCross in the original question you state "This all works fine except for setting a gridview item selected programatically. ". can you also post the code where you do that ?

Comment: It's strange, because if I call clearChoices() on the gridview followed by requestLayout() it unchecks the checkboxes.